# Write a 2D array to a CSV file in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv

I have a 2D array from a function `f.example` which returns me:

```
array([[ 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ],
       [ 5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0 ],
       [ 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0 ]])
```

In fact I am able to write it to a csv file, but just not the way I want. Here is how the csv file should look like:

```
0.0 5.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 3.0 3.0
3.0 3.0 3.0
```

But this is how it looks now:

```
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
5.0 1.0 3.0 3.0
1.0 1.0 3.0 3.0
```

And the code that I have:

```
with open('example.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(f.example)
```

Comment: Transpose the matrix before writing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *transpose* your array first

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],[5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0],[1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0 ]])
arr_t = arr.T
print(arr_t)
```

output

```
[[0. 5. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]]
```

Then follows as earlier.

Answer (score 2):

if you can't use `numpy`

code:

```
import csv
x = [[ 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ],
    [ 5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0 ],
    [ 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0 ]]
with open('example.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(list(zip(*x)))
```

result:

```
0.0,5.0,1.0

1.0,1.0,1.0

2.0,3.0,3.0

3.0,3.0,3.0
```

Comment: Thanks @leaf_yakitori, both the answers helped!